# VBA code to hide Menu, Scrollbar and etc... running in every workbook i open

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA code to hide Menu, Toolbars, Scrollbars and etc, its currently aplied on "ThisWokbook" not a Module, so that code run everytime i open the Workbook ( HAHA1.xlsm )

My Code

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ExecuteExcel4Macro "Show.Toolbar(""Ribbon"",False)"
        .WindowState = xlNormal
        .CommandBars("Full Screen").Visible = False
        .CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Enabled = False
        .DisplayStatusBar = False
        .DisplayScrollBars = False
        .DisplayFormulaBar = False
        .Width = 490
        .Height = 150
    End With
    With ActiveWindow
        .DisplayWorkbookTabs = False
        .DisplayRuler = False
        .DisplayHeadings = False
    End With
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Here is my problem, in this workbook i use this shapes to open another workbooks, but i dont wanna hide the menus and etc in these workbooks, so i want to isolate this code only to run and apply only in "HAHA1.xlsm", and if possible, I would like not to add VBA to the worksheets that are opened by the shapes, they are accounting worksheets in which I cannot modify much.

When i need to make some edit i have this code to show the hidden objects

```
Sub ShowUI()

With Application
    .ExecuteExcel4Macro "show.toolbar(""Ribbon"", True)"
    .DisplayFormulaBar = True
    .DisplayStatusBar = True
End With
With ActiveWindow
    .DisplayWorkbookTabs = True
    .DisplayHorizontalScrollBar = True
    .DisplayVerticalScrollBar = True
    .DisplayRuler = True
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: The behavior is because you're modifying the `Application` properties. Maybe you can leverage the `Workbook_Deactivate` event to reset the application state.

Comment: Where should i put it? On the code that hide the objects or on the code that calls another workbook?

Comment: Would it be more benefitial to generate this as a userform that is launched on open, whereas you would have a cancel button involved?

Comment: Sorry i dont know that much of VBA, never used userform before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [BigBen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9245853/bigben) tip I managed to solve it, my code looked like this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ExecuteExcel4Macro "Show.Toolbar(""Ribbon"",False)"
        .WindowState = xlNormal
        .CommandBars("Full Screen").Visible = False
        .CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Enabled = False
        .DisplayStatusBar = False
        .DisplayScrollBars = False
        .DisplayFormulaBar = False
        .Width = 490
        .Height = 150
    End With
    With ActiveWindow
        .DisplayWorkbookTabs = False
        .DisplayRuler = False
        .DisplayHeadings = False
    End With
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With
    
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Activate()

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ExecuteExcel4Macro "Show.Toolbar(""Ribbon"",False)"
        .WindowState = xlNormal
        .CommandBars("Full Screen").Visible = False
        .CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Enabled = False
        .DisplayStatusBar = False
        .DisplayScrollBars = False
        .DisplayFormulaBar = False
        .Width = 490
        .Height = 150
    End With
    With ActiveWindow
        .DisplayWorkbookTabs = False
        .DisplayRuler = False
        .DisplayHeadings = False
    End With
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With
    
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()

    With Application
        .ExecuteExcel4Macro "show.toolbar(""Ribbon"", True)"
        .DisplayFormulaBar = True
        .DisplayStatusBar = True
    End With
    With ActiveWindow
        .DisplayWorkbookTabs = True
        .DisplayHorizontalScrollBar = True
        .DisplayVerticalScrollBar = True
        .DisplayRuler = True
    End With

End Sub
```

So every time it open another book, it will revert the hide settings, and everytime i came back to HAHA1 it will do the settings again.
I see a small update when I go back to HAHA1: excel hiding some things, but pretty quickly.